# Iptables Proxy like setup

Tags: centos, iptables, proxy

So the situation is we're having issues forwarding packets from a particular IP on a server. This is what is happening so far.

1. Main server IP - 1.1.1.1
2. Secondary IP (what we want the client ot connec to) - 2.2.2.2:2000
3. Destination IP (where the secondary ip shoudl be forwardding packets to) - 3.3.3.3:2000

So when we set up the iptables rules as follows:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 2.2.2.2 --dport 2000 -j DNAT --to-destination 3.3.3.3:2000
```

with this as well:

```
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

It routes the packets fine to the correct port BUT notn from the 2.2.2.2 address it's routing it from 1.1.1.1. Putting in source into the POSTROUTING section as "-s 2.2.2.2" stops the routing and it doesn't work any longer.

So I'm unsure how to get it forwarding FROM the ip we want (secondary IP).

P.S Basically we have a high bandwidth DDOS Protected Dedicated Node and we're trying to distribute each IP on that protected server to a seperate game server each. e.g. 1.1.1.1:25565 to 4.4.4.4:255565 and 1.1.1.2:25565 to 22.5.1.1:25565.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`MASQUERADE` determines the source IP address automatically using your routing rules. You can use `SNAT` instead if you want to specify the source IP manually:

```
-A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source 2.2.2.2
```